# status code 500 Internal Server Error on HttpClient PostAsync

Tags: http, web-services, post, httpclient, microsoft-dynamics

I am working in C/AL in Navision.

I don't understand why I get this error from my code:

```
HttpHandler := HttpHandler.HttpClientHandler;
NCredentials := NCredentials.NetworkCredential(username, password);

HttpHandler.Credentials(NCredentials);
HttpClient := HttpClient.HttpClient(HttpHandler);
StringContent := StringContent.StringContent(txtResult);
ResponseMessage := HttpClient.PostAsync(uriString,StringContent).Result;

MESSAGE(ResponseMessage.ToString())
```

The error is:

[image]

Here is the Event Viewer Entry:
[image]

Comment: Whatever service you're calling with your `uriString` seems to be producing an internal server error - so it's a problem inside of that service - not your code shown here.

Comment: Yeah I know, but there is no way how I can check this..... This error message is sooo useless. I dont find a solution.